# extracting data from .numbers file with python

Tags: python, macos, extract

I have a .numbers file that I converted from a PDF, and I need to extract and transpose data from certain cells that are distributed every 50 rows and from columns DEF. 
for example the data is in this format, spaced through the file.

```
Año   Población Superficie
1980    2061744 12855
2000    3381005 55035
2005    3745073 58668
2010    4106054 63018
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -3):

If you are planning on doing more numerical computation, I would recommend using [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

The [np.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function provides a simple way to read in such data, allowing you to skip the header etc.

Otherwise, you could read the file line by line (skipping the first one) and use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) to obtain the column values, then converting them to floats.

Following code should work (untested):

```
ano = []
poblacion = []
superficie = []

with open("yourfile.numbers") as file:
    file.readline() # skip first line
    for line in file:
        values = map(float, line.split())
        ano.append(values[0])
        poblacion.append(values[1])
        superficie.append(values[2])
```